# Does 留言 mean "comment"?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I recently watched a show where Chinese actors read "留言" from netizens. I wonder if 留言 can be translated as "comment" (e.g in blog comment, forum comment) or it only has the meaning "message" according to dictionary.

Comment: bkrs: 留言 离去时写下的书面语言 留言薄
1) v.o. leave message/comments
2) n. short message
1) 访人不遇或自己离开时，留下要说的话。
2) 今多指用书面形式留下的话，如留言簿、留言牌。

Comment: 1. verb+object(noun): leave a message. 2. noun: left word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

留言 literally mean leave messages. In your context, it could be interpreted as 留的言, the messages left by netizens. Sometimes, 留言 can be a form of comment, or vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I agree that 留言 means comments, that are often from popular social networks like Weibo.